# File Attachment Not on a Custom Content Type (Drupal 6)

Tags: drupal

Trying to figure out why File Attachment isn't showing on a custom content type. How would I go about making sure to put it there? I can find how to add custom fields, but any of the default ones, there does not seem to be a way to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a section entitled "Attachments enabled/disabled" under edit content type.